# Android Virtual Device won't start with GPU Hardware Acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

since the update to Android Studio 2.0 AVDs won't start with GPU Hardware Acceleration enabled (this worked before), but they will without it (horribly slow). It doesn't give me any error, it just sits there with the launch command and takes up 25% CPU usage (constantly) without doing anything (waited like 20 Minutes now?). I already tried running it over the CMD, the result is just a blinking cursor. I'm running a Thinkpad x230 with all drivers updated and HAXM correctly installed (it says me that when I'm running without GPU Acceleration). Virtualisation is also enabled, but it shouldn't matter since it's the GPU Acceleration causing problems. Has anyone else experienced similar issues? It's working on my Desktop with an AMD Graphicscard, I'd guess it's an issue with the Intel HD Graphics dirvers? (Did cleaninstall the laptop today)

Cheers Andy

Comment: Have a look if hyperV is turned on in Windows,this can be a problem sometimes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem got solved in my case with the update to Android Studio 2.1.